# How to restore redis dump from version 3.2 (without docker) to 6.0 (running with bitnami docker image)

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, restore, bitnami

**Initial goal**
Currently we have an old version of redis running on a single physical server(redis v3.2.1). The goal is to have a redis/slave topology with sentinel for HA.
A way to accomplish this, is to create a slave of this single instance with version 6. Unfortunately, there is an icompatibility between version 3 and 6.

**What I try to do**

- I tried to restore the dump to version [4.0.2-r0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/redis/4.0.2-r0/images/sha256-ef2599c59e022979efafb971fee9934ce2c5acea392d8544c7b1c091115f485b?context=explore). It works fine.
- Then I tried to restore to version [4.0.2-r1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/redis/4.0.2-r1/images/sha256-bb3bfa6031bd1c1532653216f6d5149821b712818008f3864445c80459d6633f?context=explore) and it failed and the
  dump.rdb was totally replaced by an empty file automatically

**How to reproduce**

- Install a single instance of redis with :

> apt install -y redis-server redis-tools

- Create a redis container with this docker-compose.yml file

> ```
> version: '2'
>
> services:
>   redis-master:
>     #image: 'bitnami/redis:6.0'
>     #image: 'bitnami/redis:4.0.2-r1'
>     image: 'bitnami/redis:4.0.2-r0'
>     container_name: redis-master
>     volumes:
>       - 'redis_data_master:/bitnami/redis/data'
>     ports:
>       - '6379:6379'
>     environment:
>       - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
>       - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
>       - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
> volumes:
>   redis_data_master:
>     driver: local
> ```

> `docker-compose up -d`
> `docker stop redis-master`
> `# Replace` test_redis_data_master `by the right folder`
> `sudo cp dump.rdb  /var/lib/docker/volumes/test_redis_data_master/_data/dump.rdb`

With this docker compose file, it work with v4.0.2-r0 but not with v4.0.2-r1.
cf logs here:
**v4.0.2-r0**

> 30:M 01 Dec 13:52:55.993 # Server initialized   30:M 01 Dec
> 13:52:58.049 * DB loaded from disk: 2.056 seconds   30:M 01 Dec
> 13:52:58.049 * Ready to accept connections
> **The database is loaded successfully**

**v4.0.2-r1**

> 20:M 01 Dec 13:49:05.472 # Server initialized   20:M 01 Dec
> 13:49:05.472 * Ready to accept connections
> **The database is empty**

**Conclusion**
Can you please help with this issue. Did someone faced the same issue or the same situation ?
Thanks in advance for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade directly from 4.0 to 5.0?
I don't think upgrade revision by revision is a good idea since we release a new revision every day, and sometimes, they have bugs that are patched with another revision.
Apart from that, I recommend you to follow the official documentation to upgrade your databases. A major version usually means incompatible changes, so I am pretty sure you will find some issues in the way. It is highly probable that just changing the image tag will not work.